# Trying to render an alert after a redirect occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a website built on React and I have created a protected route component that basically checks if the user is logged in and if not the user will be redirected to the login page. But i'm trying to add an alert after they are redirected (on the login page) so the user has an idea of whats happened that basically says 'this page requires log in'. Although, I can't seem to get the alert to render after the redirect. Is there a way to maybe add an alert onto the redirect component? Or am I looking at this the wrong way. Anything I seem to add now just looks like it tries to render before the redirect then basically disappears.

The private route component looks like this

```
// private route component
 const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        Auth.isAuthenticated === true
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{
                 pathname: '/login',
                 state: { reason: 'user is not active' }
                }}
              /> 
    )} />
)

________________________________________________________________________________

// login class
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           showAlert: false
       }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       if (this.props.location.state.reason) {
            this.setState({showAlert: true})
       }
    }

    render() {
      return(
        <div>
           {this.state.showAlert && <div>{this.props.location.state.reason}</div>}
        </div>
     )
}
export default withRouter(Login);
```

Comment: where link is there check and then redirect. can you share your code where public route link is there and you want to alert for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data to your `login` component when redirecting,

```
<Redirect to={{
    pathname: '/login',
    state: { reason: 'User is not active' }
  }}
/>
```

In the `login` component, you should check this data in `componentDidMount` and show your `Alert`,

```
state = {
   showAlert: false
}

componentDidMount(){
   if(this.props.location.state.reason){
        //Show your alert here
       this.setState({showAlert: true})
   }
}


render(){
   return(

    {this.state.showAlert && <div>{this.props.location.state.reason}</div>}

    ...
   )
}
```

For more information on how to pass data using `redirect` check [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md#to-object).

Comment: Thanks for that, so i've tried implementing it but i've run into one issue. I've called componentDidMount() with it returning a <div> with the alert inside it. Although, the div is not rendering. I put a console.log above the return statement just to test if it was working, and that works fine. The issue just seems to be rendering to alert div

Comment: @SkinnyBetas, you should not return the `div` from `componentDidMount` instead you need to maintain a state for your alert. Check the updated answer.

Comment: hmm componentDidMount is returning an error 'this.props.location.state.reason' is undefined when I initially try and load the website

Comment: What is the version of your router?

Comment: Try this, `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'` and then wrap your component while exporting `export default withRouter(Login)`.

Comment: version 5.1.2, ill update the original post to show what it looks like now

Comment: @SkinnyBetas try this `if (this.props.location && this.props.location.state.reason)`.

Comment: it seems to be the second argument, as soon as .state is called it returns the typerror

Comment: Try to print `this.props.location` and check if you are getting `state` object.

Comment: I printed this.props.location.state successfully, and it returned an object {reason: 'user is not active'}.

Comment: Then it should pass if condition. Might be the issue is something else.

Comment: is just doesnt pass with reason added on, my guess is maybe its failing when it is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201297/discussion-between-ravibagul91-and-skinnybetas).

Comment: Just solved, just added an initial if statement that said if this.props.location.state !== null then proceed to initial if statement